# Push Laravel Applications without config information

Tags: git, github, laravel

I need to push my Laravel app in Github, I first push all the app without key in application/config/aplication.php and without credentials in application/config/database.php and then I write again all credentials in both files for my locally works and .gitignore that files but when i push again it delete that files from my repo.. How can i upload that files to my repo with no credentials and that i works fine locally too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Laravel Environment Configuration](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration) to store configuration files

Comment: And here is for L3 that's my case [L3 Environments](http://three.laravel.com/docs/install#environments)

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you correctly you don't want to make your confidential information publicly available, but still use for example github? If so here is the relevant [laravel doc](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#protecting-sensitive-configuration). However it is a little sparse.

In our current project we keep all our confidential information in .env.*enviroment-name*.php exactly as described in the docs. This file is then placed in .gitignore and every developer creates her own version. The contents of .env.*enviroment-name*.php is autoloaded into $_ENV by laravel so it's easy to access it in your config files later. The relevant part of our `app/config/database.php` file then looks something like this.

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => $_ENV['db']['host'],
        'database'  => $_ENV['db']['database'],
        'username'  => $_ENV['db']['username'],
        'password'  => $_ENV['db']['password'],
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

Comment: +1 for the Laravel doc on this. I looked around and it seem most people just put their sensitive data in git. Ha.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you have a different directory for your Github repos. And then do your work on your local server, when you are happy with it, copy it to your Github directory. If you don't want the credentials to appear in your Github repo, then edit these out from the copy in the Github directory.
Then sync the two.